# Bootstrap button and schementic

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility

I saw a bootstrap example for their button list and it kinda bugged me in many ways and I was wondering what would be the best way to do it AND if bootstrap are right. Here it is:

[Example from bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-single)

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

I'll break my questions in many few points:

**1. Should'nt the `btn-group` div be a `ul` and every button be in a list item?**

To me, it seems like it's a unordered list of button and every button is an element from the list.

**2. I'll use them in a loop, and I'm wondering if you can give aria-label can be the same for multiple element or if it has to be unique in the page?**

**3. Is the `role="group"` needed on the `div` if we use a list instead of a `div`?**

**4. Isn't it a mistake to put `role="button"` on the element `button` since it's already the button element? I'd put `type="button"` on element such as a `div` that has a button behavior (for example)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It wouldn't make sense to use list items instead of buttons, a button is a single UI element, being able to group them together by simple wrapping them in a parent element is very efficient. Additionally buttons already use lists to create button dropdowns which on the other hand is an effective use for lists in this context.
2. There are no restrictions on how many times you can use the same aria-label on a page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute
3. If you WERE to use a list, the group role has no implications on the styling of the group (the buttons are styled using the btn-group class)
4. Assigning role="button" to a button has nothing to do with the buttons type, it's used for accessibility - have a read through this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role

Comment: Sorry maybe I exprimed myself wrong, for the point #1, it would be a button but the button would be inside the list-item element

Comment: @YannChabot It would be inefficient, lists require more markup than simply grouping buttons (which don't actually need to be buttons, they could be anchors or other elements with the class .btn) and come with different computed styles (lists are inherently vertical so you'd need to use a modified inline list, buttons are inline-block elements and require no additional styling). Keep in mind you're using a UI framework, a lot of thought has gone into making each element reusable and semantic.

Comment: I feel you. I understand that it is, mark-up wise, not the best to put a list, but schementically, it feels to me like a button group is a list of button right? I'm experienced with bootstrap and I feel like usually they are always right about the markup but this time I wasn't sure. Anyways, thanks for your answer very constructive!

Comment: @YannChabot Think of lists in terms of hierarchy, the reason they're used for menus and navigation is because they can be nested and generally container an anchor with text - buttons can't (or at the very least shouldn't) be nested within each other so it doesn't make sense to use the extra markup. Once you need to use a button dropdown however lists come into play, but you'll notice they also contain only anchors and text and can be nested.

Comment: Normally role=button on a button would be redundant, but if the button is to act like a toggle and you combine it with aria-pressed it will provide more information to screenreader software.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the buttons bootstrap exactly the same way as in the example. You can turn on the list if you want. I once replaced my button on the a normal anchor.

It looked something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"></a>
```

Just use the performance the same class name.

You do not need to use the role = "group".